# think in OO by a procedural guy

Tags: object, procedural-programming

I'm on the stage of learning cakephp, which is a OO based framework, but i have not a good understanding of OO. I come from  C procedural field.

I need something which can help me think in OO perspective. Can you advicxe me about what can I do/read/watch.... in order to help me think in OO.

Comment: see this answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural/1848715#1848715 for starters

Comment: @rabidmachine: it's true that i didn't use to "accept", but i rank all the useful answers. TY for your advice, I'll follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand five concepts : classes ; inheritance ; the notion of private and public ; abstraction ; polymorphism. Those last two are the trickiest to understand.

No need for a book, for that. Just read any tutorial about OO PHP. Try to code a few mock classes, use inheritance and polymorphism. Make sure you understand those five concepts, up to the point you don't have to think when you hear the word to remember what they are.

And then, once you've understood all that, buy some books about OOP (Head First, as suggested by Boris Pavlovic, is a good choice).

Then, read about design patterns, even though you do not intend to use them : frameworks use (and often abuse !) design patterns, so you will have to understand them (at least, know more or less what they're about).

Comment: ty for your answer. Besides abstraction I'm good with the concepts mentioned by you.  At the fist sight, it seems that in OO is also some procedural thinking, but the objects are mixing the data between them. Is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean. You could say (from a C point of view) that "OOP" is just having structs with their own functions. But you'd be missing the "abstraction" problem, and it is the heart of the matter. Once you've understood the need for, and the usefulness, of abstraction, you'll get a much better understanding of the OOP philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice to read GoF design patterns. maybe not for the beginner, but a really helpful knowledge, it explains for what OOP can be helpful. There are a number of books about design patterns.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the general understanding of OOP, you can refer the book "Object Oriented Thought Process".

Answer (score 2):

[Head First: Object Oriented Analysis and Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596008678) is a very good book which may be followed by [Head First: Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) from the same series.

Answer (score 1):

Generally,Nouns in requirements translates to classes in your application.
This is not a rule of thumb but happens in most cases.

Please give a look at this book [Object-Oriented-Design-Heuristics by Arthur-Riel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163385X).