# Creating a new ID using mysqli_insert_id and storing in session

Tags: php, mysqli

This was working fine before and now it's not. I'll try explain the problem best I can.

I am creating a website where people post ads for horses they are trying to sell, or put on loan - people can also post if they are looking for a specific horse. 
I am using this code to create a new ID once an advert has been posted, because once the ad is posted, it takes them to a page where they can upload a picture. This part of my code isn't working.

```
        if ($conn->query($sql)) {

        // echo "New Record has id ".$conn->mysqli_insert_id;

        $_SESSION['hid'] = $conn->mysqli_insert_id;
```

$conn is the variable I use when connecting to the DB so no problem there. No ID is being generated but yesterday it was fine and nothing changed since then. Any tips or anything I could be doing wrong?

Comment: `$conn->insert_id` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an object for your connection in `$conn` variable.
This means that you are taking the object oriented approach versus the procedural approach. You then used `mysqli_insert_id` which is a procedural function.

You have two options:

**1. Object Oriented Approach** 
use `insert_id` as a property of `$conn`.

```
$_SESSION['hid'] = $conn->insert_id;
```

**2. Procedural Approach** 
use the procedural function `mysqli_insert_id` if no object was created.

```
mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

Read manual [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

More Info:  [Object-Oriented Programming vs. Procedural Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural)