# Mysqli fetch_object is giving me hassles

Tags: php, mysqli

All this section is supposed to do is collect an int from active and use it in the if statement to continue with the code. Can somebody please tell me why this is not working?

```
$act_qry = "Select active FROM user_m WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$Menrypted_password'";
$result_act = mysqli_query ( $connMS, $act_qry );
$value_act = mysqli_fetch_object($result_act);

if($value_act == 1)
{
    //Do php stuff.
}
```

Comment: Change like:-`if($value_act->active == 1)
{
    //Do php stuff.
}`

Comment: Use **var_dump($value_act);** to see what is being returned

Comment: var_dump($value_act) = object(stdClass)#5 (1) {  ["active"]=>  string(1) "1"}

Comment: @GenGen DID YOU TRIED WHAT I SUGGESTED TO YOU

Comment: @A-2-A Can you show me that code in procedural style, oriented style doesnt click with me.

Comment: If you don't want object oriented then don't fetch as an object...`mysqli_fetch_object`.. Also use prepared statements in the future, that could be an issue for you in the future..

Comment: @chris85 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural

You can use procedural for mysqli_fetch_object

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-object.php

Comment: @GenGen What you linked shows the usage `$value_act->active`... so what is the question then? Note the usage of `$obj` in example #1 and #2 on the manual's page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having this table in my database:-http://prntscr.com/9tnalx

Check this code:-

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
//connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','stack');
$act_qry = "Select product_id FROM bom WHERE bom_description = 'Table Tops'";
$result_act = mysqli_query ( $link, $act_qry ) or die(mysqli_error($link));

$value_act = mysqli_fetch_object($result_act);

if($value_act->product_id == 1)
{
    echo $value_act->product_id;
}
// or you can do this 

$value_act = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_act);

    if($value_act['product_id'] == 1)
    {
        echo $value_act->product_id;
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

Output on my browser:- http://prntscr.com/9tnazj

Note:- I hope you can understand the code by checking my screenshot of table.Thanks

Comment: if($value_act->product_id == 1)  How would I write that using procedural style?

Comment: Although I dont fully understand the $value_act->product_id it does work what I needed it to. Thank you @A-2-A.

Comment: @GenGen Note the `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is returning an array. When you ask for an object, `mysqli_fetch_object`, you get an object.

Comment: Thanks @GenGen. Since `$value_act` is an object so if you want to get any property of that object then you have to do `$object name->property name`. I added another one in my code also