# Insert database not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Hi Im working on a school project and i cant insert this into the database

What am I doring wrong? I dont have any error`s so I im stuck. Please help me. I do have a connection to the database. But the things I insert into the form do not show in to the databse.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root123";
$dbname = "ToetsPro";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
    $query = "INSERT INTO `opleiding` (`id`,
                                   `opleiding`,
                                   `locatie`) 
              VALUES              (NULL,
                                   '".$_POST["opleiding"]."',
                                   '".$_POST["locatie"]."');";
    //echo $query; exit();                     
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<form id="register" action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Opleiding: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="opleiding"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Locatie: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="locatie"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<a href="index.php">Terug naar de homepage</a>
```

Comment: Is id an auto increment field? Remove it from that query. Else ID cannot be NULL

Comment: For one thing your code is wide open to SQL injection, so you're not even really controlling what SQL code you execute in the first place.  Additionally, you should use `mysqli_error($conn)` to check for errors if `mysqli_query` is returning false.  It's *probably* failing because you're trying to insert `NULL` for an `id`, and it's unlikely that an identifying column allows nulls.

Comment: You do not have any error because you do not check for any. Check for sql errors after calling `mysqli_query()` using `mysqli_error()`.

Comment: if you really want to check your query. copy the output of your `echo $query;` and run that query in your phpmyadmin or workbench or whatever sql software you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doring wrong? I dont have any error`s so I im stuck.

well there are few things you doing wrong.

**one** of the very first things I have noticed is that you are mixing up [Object oriented style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural) and [Procedural style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530868/simple-explanation-php-oop-vs-procedural)
 doing so might confuse you in the long run.

here your db connection

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

You using mysqli object oriented style

Then here : `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);` You using procedural style. I suggest that you only stick with one style, in that way you can easily read,organize and maintain your code.

**two** : You might be making an error with your insert statement, `id` then inserting a `null` on the ID that might be the problem, if your id is an `auto_increment` better not even include it within your query.

**three** You are writing a dangerous code, that will harm your application in the long run. you are directly inject `$_POST` values in your query, that might dangerous and it leave your application wide open to [sql injections](http://bobby-tables.com/about)

You should learn to use [**prepared statements**](http://bobby-tables.com/php), with [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO prepared statements](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

This is how your code should look :

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root123";
$dbname     = "ToetsPro";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //check and validate your inputs

    $opleiding = $_POST['opleiding'];
    $locatie   = $_POST['locatie'];


    $query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `opleiding` (opleiding,locatie)VALUES(?,?)");
    $query->bind_param("ss", $opleiding, $locatie);

    if ($query->execute()) {

        echo "success";
        $id->insert_id;
    } else {

        echo "Error :" . $conn->error;
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<form id="register" action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Opleiding: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="opleiding"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Locatie: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="locatie"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<a href="index.php">Terug naar de homepage</a>
```

Comment: Upvoted for showing a secure query process.  @Kenneth If this isn't the accepted answer, please explain what isn't working as expected and perhaps post the database structure in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for every variable data filtering then your query should like this way:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `opleiding` (`id`,`opleiding`,`locatie`) VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['opleiding']."','".$_POST['locatie']."')";
```

Comment: i think you should demonstrate how he should use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`